# Angular CLI/Webpack add styles to body instead of head

Tags: angular, webpack

In my Angular 6 application, when I compile it for production, I have a stylesheet link to the compiled CSS in my head. However, this prevents my loading animation from being displayed while the stylesheet loads. If I move the link to body, everything works fine. Is there a switch I can flip to do this at compile time?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/how-to-style-angular-application-loading-with-angular-cli-like-a-boss-cdd4f5358554